# How can I do join on selected text only?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables. I need to join these tables using substring function. I tried something like this. But its not working...

Table01

```
ID  NameStreet
1   Julian Assange 100 Majestic street, Toronto
2   Brad Pit 200 Loaden Blvd, Toronto
3   Allen Sunderland 9, Unit 2, Janet Street, BC
4   Julian Assange 50 Majectic street, Toronto
```

Table02

```
ID Name
1  Julian Assange
2  Allen Sunderland 
3  Julian Assange
```

Current query (not working)

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table01 t1 
JOIN Table02 t2 
ON t2.Name = SUBSTRING(t1.NameStreet, 0, CHARINDEX(t2.Name, t1.NameStreet))
```

Expecting Results:-

```
1   Julian Assange 100 Majestic street, Toronto
3   Allen Sunderland 9, Unit 2, Janet Street, BC
4   Julian Assange 50 Majectic street, Toronto
```

Comment: Do you want it to only match on words, or on first characters?  That is, what if `NameStreet` starts with 'Allen Sunderlander' (or whatever) - do you want that returned as well?

Comment: X-Zero. It should be exact match.

Comment: What other stuff do we need to watch out for?  Would there be people with multiple names (ie Allen Sunderland Forks) - and how confident are you that names will always be entered the same way?  What about addresses that have non-numeric beginnings - how could we detect the end of the name and the start of the address?  This could potentially be impossible to implement... (and why are you doing this anyways, do you not have access to a normalized, sensible representation?)

Comment: X-Zero. Table2 -> Name column is kind of master list.

Comment: X-Zero: Marc 2nd solution is working but it gives me dupes because table2 has duplicate records. How to avoid it?

Comment: His suggestion should work, unless there are _completely identical_ records in `Table01` that you want multiple copies of.  Do you have duplicate data in `Table01` or not (your example doesn't show that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this in your query:

```
on t2.Name = LEFT(t1.NameStreet, (charindex(' ', t1.NameStreet)-1) )
```

EDIT

Does this work?

```
on t2.Name = LEFT(t1.NameStreet, Len(t2.Name) )
```

Comment: Marc: Whitespace ' ' wont work in expressionToFind. Name cant be something like this 'Julian Assange'

Comment: I like the way you're thinking, but this is going to have problems if the column he's trying to match on contains a space.  Also, I'm a bit surprised you can subtract a number from a string that way - should it have been _outside_ the `CHARINDEX()` function?

Comment: Your examples don't illustrate that case

Comment: Updated my answer, but I don't have a way to test it, so I'm just guessing it might work.

Comment: It worked. One little problem. Table2 has two similar record records coz of that I am getting duplicate records from table1

Comment: If you're getting dupes, `Select Distinct`

Comment: Distinct will introduce more problems. If Table1 has duplicate then show duplicates in results... but if Table2 has duplicates then show once...

Comment: Are you sure there are problems with using `Distinct`?  Did you try it?